# Send custom data to google analytics from server side

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to send these information `title`, `target amount`, `category`, `account name` to GA for every user who creates a page in our website. And if anyone make transaction on that page I want to generate a `revenue` of 5% based on the transaction amount for every transaction. I've no clue how to do that.

So far what I've achieved is I set up the service account by following [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) and create a custom dimension. Playing with the code snippet I can update the name of the dimension and other things but not sure how to send an object value with all the fields that I need in this custom dimension. My question is if I call this again will it update and replace the old value with the new value? I don't want that. Every time I want to insert a new value in the old value. Shall I need another dimension and what if I want to relate this custom dimension data to ecommerce later on. How can I do that?

```
try:
  analytics.management().customDimensions().update(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
      customDimensionId='ga:dimension2',
      body={
          'name': 'Campaign Group',
          'scope': 'SESSION',
          'active': True
      }
  ).execute()
```

Can someone please suggest me what should I do here.

Answer (score 0):

you use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) to send data to google analytics.  The google analytics management api is only for managing your google analytics account.

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

payload_data
```

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, thanks for your reply. I send a post request like this `http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=item&tid=UA-XXXXX-1&cid=1234589-adsfsadfasdfada.apps.googleusercontent.com&payload=test&ti=something` but don't see any changes in google analytics

Answer (score 0):

This article should help you achieve what you want.
Basically the custom dimensions in your url should be like cd1, cd2 so on...

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#customs

Here is a code sample that might help 
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/13-useful-custom-dimensions-for-google-analytics/#23-payload-length